# Getting id from UL when clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get `OptionGroupID` and `optionName` from `ul` when you click on the Add button?

For example:

```
<ul id="formAddOption_4" class="formStyle">
   <li> 
     <input id="OptionGroupID" type="hidden" value="4"> 
     <div style="font-size:10px;"> Option Name: </div> 
     <input id="optionName" type="text">
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="button" class="buttonAddOption" value="Add Option"> 
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="formAddOption_5" class="formStyle">
   <li> 
     <input id="OptionGroupID" type="hidden" value="5"> 
     <div style="font-size:10px;"> Option Name: </div> 
     <input id="optionName" type="text">
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="button" class="buttonAddOption" value="Add Option"> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried this but it dont work:

```
$(".buttonAddOption").click(function() {
  var OptionForm = $(this).closest("ul");
  //Get Group ID
  alert( OptionForm.$("#OptionGroupID").val() );
});
```

Comment: IDs have to be **unique** throughout the whole document.

Comment: It means no two elements should have the same ID. In your HTML, two elements have the ID `OptionGroupID`. That is not valid.

Comment: I guess the same with optionName as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".buttonAddOption").click(function() {
    var OptionForm = $(this).closest("ul");
    alert( OptionForm.find("#OptionGroupID").val() );
});
```

Notice that I've used `OptionForm.find` (looks for descendants). FYI: IDs are unique, so you should probably give each input a class instead and find it like so: `OptionForm.find(".OptionGroupID")`.

Comment: Thanks! That work. What do you mean by "probably give each input a class " .. can you provide example of that how would that work.

Comment: @user: Instead of `id="..."` you use `class="..."`.